# Most effient way of List/Dict Lookups in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries. Which looks something like,

```
abc = [{"name":"bob",
        "age": 33},
       {"name":"fred",
        "age": 18},
       {"name":"mary",
        "age": 64}]
```

Lets say I want to lookup bobs age. I know I can run a for loop through etc etc. However my questions is are there any quicker ways of doing this. 
One thought is to use a loop but break out of the loop once the lookup (in this case the age for bob) has been completed.

The reason for this question is my datasets are thousands of lines long so Im looking for any performance gains I can get.

Edit : I can see you can use the following via the use of a generator, however im not too sure whether this would still iterate over all items of the list or just iterate until the the first dict containing the name bob is found ?

```
next(item for item in abc if item["name"] == "bob")
```

Thanks,

Comment: You could sort the list by name. That'll get you to an O(logn) lookup time as opposed to an O(n) lookup time

Comment: Or you could just flatten it into a single dictionary, which will get you O(1) lookup time. For a real-life use case, unlike this toy example, that may not be possible. You still might be able to (and want to) create an "index dictionary". If not, then sorting is usually the best answer.

Comment: @abarnert: I can think of ONE usecase where that won't be applicable (OP hasn't mentioned this, but I think he just forgot): what happens if you have multiple people named "Alice"?

Comment: In the real life scenerio there will be no duplicates. But fair point.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: That's the most obvious one, but I wouldn't bet on it being the _only_ one. For example, imagine the names were some class that isn't hashable, but is still orderable (e.g., mutable strings).

Answer (score 7):

Depending on how many times you want to perform this operation, it might be worth defining a dictionary mapping names to the corresponding age (or the list of corresponding ages if more than two people can share the same name).

A dictionary comprehension can help you:

```
abc_dict = {x["name"]:x["age"] for x in abc}
```

Comment: `dict` and `list` are probably bad name choices, but other than that, this is the way to go.

Comment: Also, that's a dict comprehension, not a set comprehension.

Comment: Duplicated names will break or get incorrect result with this method. The list of dictionaries could contain multiple Bob dicts.

Comment: @Prashant: Actually, it won't. His intended linear search would only find one of those Bob dicts; so will this dictionary. (If we adds to the specification that it must always give the first Bob, or the last Bob, or some other rule, you may have to break the comprehension out into an explicit loop as in Mark R. Wilkins' answer.)

Answer (score 4):

I'd consider making another dictionary and then using that for multiple age lookups:

```
for person in abc:
    age_by_name[person['name']] = person['age']

age_by_name['bob']
# this is a quick lookup!
```

Edit:  This is equivalent to the dict comprehension listed in Josay's answer

Comment: Thanks for catching a couple problems in my example, inspectorG4dget!

Answer (score 1):

Try indexing it first (once), and then using the index (many times).

You can index it eg. by using `dict` (keys would be what you are searching by, while the values would be what you are searching for), or by putting the data in the database. That should cover the case if you really have a lot more lookups and rarely need to modify the data.

Answer (score 1):

define dictionary of dictionary like this only

```
peoples = {"bob":{"name":"bob","age": 33},
"fred":{"name":"fred","age": 18},
"mary": {"name":",mary","age": 64}}
person = peoples["bob"]
persons_age = person["age"]
```

look up "bob" then look up like "age"

this is correct no ?

Comment: I'd argue that the "name" key isn't even needed.

Answer (score 0):

You might write a helper function. Here's a take.

```
import itertools

# First returns the first element encountered in an iterable which 
# matches the predicate.
#
# If the element is never found, StopIteration is raised.
# Args:
#    pred The predicate which determines a matching element.
#    
first = lambda pred, seq: next(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: not pred(x), seq))
```

Comment: This is essentially just a less readable version of alexce's answer. In particular, it will not help the performance problem the OP is trying to solve any more than his answer will.

Comment: Also, why would you ever write `first = lambda pred, seq:` instead of just `def first(pred, seq):`? The only reasons to use `lambda` are when you don't have a good name, or when you need it to be in an expression. By assigning it to a variable, you're giving up both of those benefits.

Comment: @abarnet alecxe's version requires that you inline the test. I like passing the test as a param. Also, actually using my version looks like `first(test, seq)` which is pretty readable to me.

Comment: @abarnert I've not "given up the benefit" of number one. Using lambda is a style thing - doesn't bother me for something so simple, but thanks for the comment. Your way is probably best practice for real code.

Comment: I don't see how you think you still have the benefit of "no name needed" when you've explicitly given it a name. And yes, overusing lambdas is a style thing, but it's an explicitly un-pythonic style. If you really want to write Lisp or Haskell, there are better languages for that than Python, like Lisp and Haskell.